# Can I adjust command line output to make columns vertically align?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, conemu, cmder

The first image is Mac terminal output, these columns are vertically aligned.

[image]

This is Windows `cmder` output, in a mess. Can I adjust it?

[image]

Comment: What font are you using on Windows? It should be a fixed width font. What program is generating the output?

Comment: What application are you using for your command line? The default Windows one doesn't do transparency like that.

Comment: @DavidPostill I forgot about that. It is Cmder, and as your tips I changed the font, now it display things perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidPostill I always forget about about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I adjust the command line output to make columns vertically align?

You are using a variable width font in your program (`cmder`).

To get your display to line up correctly you need to use a fixed width ([monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)) font.

Monospaced fonts are normally used for terminal, IDE and programming text editors. See below for some good reasons to do this.

> Even though computers can now display a wide variety of fonts, the majority of IDEs and software text editors employ a monospaced font as the default typeface. This increases the readability of source code, which is often heavily reliant on distinctions involving individual symbols, and makes differences between letters more unambiguous in situations like password entry boxes where typing mistakes are unacceptable.[2] Monospaced fonts are also used in terminal emulation and for laying out tabulated data in plain text documents. In technical manuals and resources for programming languages, a monospaced font is often used to distinguish code from natural-language text.

Source [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill says using monospaced fonts is preferred way. These fonts are shown bold in Font list box.

[image]

However, you may try to use proportional fonts and force ConEmu to treat them as monospaced. Just check `Monospace` checkbox and (optionally) experiment with `Width` and `Cell` fields. `Cell` will reserve width for character.

[image]